# Ezpublish create new Mysql database after the old Mysql database got deleted

Tags: mysql, database, content-management-system, ezpublish

Recently I setup a website on byethost.com using the CMS ezpublish. After a couple days of working on the site, byethost deleted the Mysql database. I still have all the FTP files but I can't log in as an admin because their is not Mysql database with all the users. Is there any way I can create a new Mysql database setup for Ezpublish. All I need currently is an admin account and whatever other information is essential to have for Ezpublish to run. Any response/ideas would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Just [create a new database](http://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Installation/Normal-installation/Installing-eZ-Publish-on-a-Linux-UNIX-based-system)

Then, for a plain site (not ezflow neither ezwebin) import those files : `kernel/sql/mysql/kernel_schema.sql` and `kernel/sql/common/cleandata.sql` in MySQL.

The admin username will be : `admin` and the admin password will be : `publish`

By the way, an other solution is to edit `settings/override/site.ini.append.php` and change this:

```
[SiteAccessSettings]
CheckValidity=false
```

to this:

```
[SiteAccessSettings]
CheckValidity=true
```

Reloading a page will lead to launch the setup wizard just like if it was a fresh install. (If it doesn't work, you may need to clear the cache by yourself and try again)